# Свертывание списка в случае превышения кол-ва элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не знаю как свернуть список  на сайте, полагаю что как-то реализовывается на js. Суть в том, чтобы при превышении кол-ва элементов li срабатывало условие: если более 1-го элемента то показывается только 1 элемент, а остальные элементы сворачивались в кнопку "Посмотреть все", и если нажать на кнопку, то увидеть весь список и при повторном нажатии "Свернуть" все обратно сворачивалось кроме 1-го элемента

```html
<ul>
<li>
Элемент списка 1
</li>
<li>
  Элемент списка 2
</li>
<li>
  Элемент списка 3
</li>
<li>
Элемент списка 4
</li>
</ul>
```

Надо чтоб был виден только первый а остальные разворачивались и сворачивались по клику на "Посмотреть все" и "Свернуть"

Надеюсь я правильно объяснил, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надеюсь, что из комментариев в коде JS, будет всё понятно. Со стилями, думаю, сами разберётесь.

```js
(function() {
  // Получаем все обёртки со списками
  var DIVs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.custom'));
  // Перебираем найденные элементы "div"
  DIVs.forEach(function(div) {
    // Получаем в текущем "div" все "li", которые не являются первыми
    var LIs = Array.prototype.slice.call(div.querySelectorAll('li:not(:first-child)'));
    // Если таковые найдены, тогда...
    if (LIs.length) {
      // Создаем кнопку
      var btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
      // Устанавливаем начальный текст для кнопки
      btn.innerText = 'Посмотреть ещё ' + LIs.length;
      // Назначаем кнопке обработчик события "onclick"
      // При клике...
      btn.onclick = function() {
        // Перебираем найденные элементы "li"
        LIs.forEach(function(li) {
          // Добавляем/удаляем класс "show"
          li.classList.toggle('show');
        });
        // Меняем текст на кнопке
        this.innerText = (this.innerText != 'Свернуть') ? 'Свернуть' : 'Посмотреть ещё ' + LIs.length;
      }
      // Добавляем кнопку в "div"
      div.appendChild(btn);
    }
  })
})()
```

```css
.custom {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 180px;
}

ul {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
}

li.show {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 30px;
}

li:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

button {
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Элемент списка 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Элемент списка 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Элемент списка 3
    </li>
    <li>
      Элемент списка 4
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="custom">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Элемент списка 1
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="custom">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Элемент списка 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Элемент списка 2
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```